# 'confirmPassword' is assigned a value but never used.eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, destructuring

I know the way to fix the "unused error in eslint" but I am wondering **if the variable in the first destructuring part is mandatory or I can just leave it as** const [, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

Below is my code

```
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");
```

Thank you and sorry for being a noob...
#I am new and first time to ask here, sorry if disturbing your time helping me

I've tried to run my file and it works fine but I want to know the best practice and clear my doubt. From what I search from the other forum they said it might waste the space and affect the run of the program so I am confuse whether it is okay to leave it with unused OR is it correct if I leave it blank.

Comment: You can leave it, but what would be the sense of using a setter without actually reading the value?

Answer (score 0):

Usually in ESLint you can prefix a variable with an underscore to show that you're deliberately assigning a value, but don't plan to use it. This is also useful in cases where you're ignoring the first argument in a function:

```js
// don't need to read value of password
const [_confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("");

// only need to use second argument in callback
someObject.runCallback((_, b) => {console.log(b)})
```

In most cases, assigning an extra variable has low performance costs relative to the overhead of the code being less readable. If you need to fix a bug, or rewrite some code, or add a new feature, and in the past used some workaround to avoid assigning the variable, and that adds an extra ten minutes to development time because the code's less readable, that's *probably* more value lost than assigning an extra variable.

---

In your code snippet specifically, it's not clear why you need a setter but not a getter. There's no larger context in your question but I suspect that as you work on this piece of code you'll find a reason that you do need to use `confirmPassword` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Like Dakeyras's answer says underscores can be used to ignore a variable, but you can also use your own regular expressions with the `varsIgnorePattern` attribute to achieve the same.

[Documentation:](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern)

> The varsIgnorePattern option specifies exceptions not to check for usage: variables whose names match a regexp pattern. For example, variables whose names contain ignored or Ignored.

> Examples of correct code for the { "varsIgnorePattern": "[iI]gnored" } option:

```js
/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "[iI]gnored" }]*/

var firstVarIgnored = 1;
var secondVar = 2;
console.log(secondVar);
```